# SQLException: Cannot absolute position to row 0

Tags: java, mysql

My code produces the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot absolute position to row 0
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the code which is causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: Or - if you don't have that - google your error message first rather than posting it here

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38252

Comment: Jon Skeet, it is a big project with 5000 lines of code with diffrent classes.. And please Pelle you really dont think I did that? but yeah any.. ;)

Comment: I think I've seen this if I try to read from a ResultSet without doing  a ".next()" on it first.

Comment: Jon isn't asking for your whole program, just the bit that caused the exception.

Comment: Thanks, you where right. I didnt to a ".next()" =), but jesus I am new here and I get this kind of responed, take it easy.. But thanks for all the help!

Comment: Well, there should be a stacktrace (unless something is very wrong) which should point you to the location where the Exception was thrown.

Comment: Post the stack trace if you can.  That can be enough info to help answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Most things in the JDBC API are 1-based.  The first column of a ResultSet is 1; the first parameter of a prepared statement is 1; and the first row of a scrollable resultset is 1.

You probably tried to set the current row to 0.

Comment: This would be my guess with the limited info presented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JDBC bug as specified in this link: [Bug link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38252)

I also got into this issue. It happens when you try to position the cursor at absolute 0 with an open resultset.

Work-around for this issue:

```
if(pos!=0)
    resultset.absolute(pos);
else
    resultset.beforeFirst();
```